# how to handle keyboard input in appium for ios in javascript?

Tags: javascript, automation, appium-ios

For our app, we are doing automation using appium in JavaScript. In one screen, we need to enter a PIN from the keyboard.

I have tried *pressKeyCode(Keycode)* for Android and I was able to handle keyboard input.

Can someone help me in fining a way to enter number in iOS using some method ? *pressKeycode(keycode)* is not working in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using the *Sendkeys()* function:

```
 element.Sendkeys("12");
```

If this doesn't fulfill your needs, please post some code and we can help further.